# Split wires for the purpose of measuring high currents

Tags: power-measurement

According to *[I need an amp meter that requires no splitting of the wires](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191034/i-need-an-amp-meter-that-requires-no-splitting-of-the-wires/191035)* there is an [accessory](https://www.amprobe.com/product/els2a/) that splits wires for the purposes of measuring current.

From the looks of the device it's limited to 110V/15A circuits (or maybe 110V 30A at most).  I need something like that but for higher amperages.

I would like to do the same thing but for the following types of circuits

1. 30 to 50A 208V attached with twistlock adapter
2. 20 to 50A 208V to 480V permanently installed by qualified electrician but safely accessible by anyone to clamp onto with amp meter

Is there a plug-in solution at these higher currents?  Or better yet for case 2) could this be improvised asking the electrician to split the wires by means of a junction box?

Comment: Questions seeking products and where to buy them are closed very quickly. I suggest that you remove that part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, made the edit now.   I don't need a product.  I just need to know how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The Amprobe ELS2A has a mains plug at the top and a socket at the bottom. A clamp-on ammeter can be attached to either side of either hole with the clamp faces closing in the hole.*

That device is just a plug and socket connected with, I presume, the live wire running down one side and the neutral and earth running down the other. Clamping on either side should give a reading of the current being drawn by the device plugged into the socket.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8adlO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A home-made version.*

A similarly functioning device could be made by using plastic junction boxes at the top and bottom connected by two plastic conduits. The input and output cables would use gland fittings where they enter and leave the box.

Comment: The device you show is only rated for 15 amp max. which was noted by the OP. Clamp on ammeters can measure hundreds of amperes but require access to one wire.

Comment: Thanks, @Barry. The ELS2A is the device referenced by the OP in the question but s/he didn't include a photo. My solution is Figure 2.

Comment: @Transistor, this is the answer I was looking for but I am worried about the word "home-made".   If I show this diagram to an electrician can they do this and will it be up to North American electrical code?

Comment: Ask a North American electrician. I'm in Ireland.

Comment: @user3280964 Canadian here.  One option you'd have is just to use cable rated for rugged use (cabtire (SOOW 600V) or the like.  I just got home so I don't want to dig out my codebook right this moment to look up the perfect wire type for you, but you want a cable type that is for heavy use, more than sufficient voltage, more than adequate ampacity, and finely stranded.  Single conductor cabtire would be ideal.  Then you can take a male and female of whatever plug type and wire them together so you have durable, flexible, accessable wires in between.

Comment: If you get the electrician to choose your wire right it will be both legal in your area and no more dangerous than handling a 208V extension cord.  I'd only build the plastic portable version if you expect very heavy, long or strenuous use, or if you don't need many of the device in total.  For case 2, if it were indoor the boxes need not be plastic so long as the ground connects to all metal parts and the pipes between are plastic.  For the cost of 2 more PVC connectors and 5cm pipe, if you're building your own, feel free to give yourself separate access to the ground wire.